# How do I get LibreOffice Extensions to work in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, libreoffice, plugins

I installed `Ubuntu 12.04` and am unable to run the LibreOffice Extensions that ran perfectly in earlier versions of LibreOffice & in `Ubuntu 11.10`.

The error Message states `Could not create Java implementation loader`.

Please help.

LibreOffice 3.5.2.2 
Build ID: 350m1(Build:202)

Comment: What version(s) or Java, JRE, OpenJDK, etc. do you have loaded?  Is this Ubuntu 12.04 (fresh install) or upgraded from (eg.) 11.10 ?

Comment: @david6 Hi David, I have libreoffice-java-common. I do not have OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime (or 6) or Icedtea Java plugin. This is a fresh install (not upgrade).

Comment: @david6 Hi, I solved this problem when I got a hint from your question. I installed OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime through the Ubuntu Software center & restarted LO. Thereafter, I tried the extensions examples Language Tool etc. They all work fine now. Many thanks!

Comment: sorry.  It was my Sunday/weekend (in Australia), and I meant to suggest something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an extension (example Ooo2gd) with LibreOffice or OpenOffice.org in Ubuntu, follow the steps below:

1. You need to install Java.

In Ubuntu Software Center search "Java"

Install OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime

2, For LibreOffice, install "libreoffice-java-common":
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-java-common

For OpenOffice.org, run the command below:
sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-java-common

3, Close LibreOffice / OpenOffice, download the latest extension in your home folder (~/) and go to 'Tools' then 'Extension Manager' & then add the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how LibreOffice was pulled in, you may not have the full suite installed.  For many years, the default install from the Ubuntu and Debian CD has left out dependencies on Java and LibreOffice Base.

To get the full package, install "libreoffice", which will pull in Java, Base, etc.

There is a blueprint for improving the user experience, error messages etc: [LibreOffice package split collateral damage analysis - Ubuntu Developer Summit for Quantal Quetzal](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-q/meeting/20569/desktop-q-libreoffice-split/)